# Variable is defined but still getting error not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why am I getting error

> getiata is undefined

```js
function getUrlVars() {
  var vars = {};
  var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
    function(m, key, value) {
      vars[key] = value;
    });
  return vars;
}
var getiata = getUrlVars()["i"];

if (getiata.substr(0, 2) == "DS") {
  //do some stuff
}
}
```

Comment: At which line is this error reported? maybe you are using the variable before defining it

Comment: `getiata` can have the value `undefined` if `getUrlVars` doesn't return an object with property `i`. You should verify that `getUrlVars` actually returns. We cannot help you since we don't know.

Comment: As you can see in the formatted snippet, the script you posted is not valid JS - there is a `}` too many

Comment: ["i"] is undefined there in var getiata = getUrlVars()["i"];

Comment: @azizsagi `getUrlVars()` might return a JSON object, which might contain a key named `i` so the syntax is OK. But it might also be an array, and `i` is an iterator. In that case the `i` should not be enclosed in double quotes. Who knows?

Comment: Okay you can change it to as follow

var getiata = getUrlVars();
console.log(getiata["i"]);

it is undefined because the object don't contain anything like ["i"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many assumptions and do not code defensively.

Here I do not assume the url contains any parameters at all.

```js
function getUrlVars(url) {
  var vars = {};
  var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
  var parts = href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
    function(m, key, value) {
      vars[key] = value;
    });
  return vars;
}
var getiata = getUrlVars("?i=DS3"); // change to getUrlVars() to use location
console.log(getiata)
if (getiata["i"] && getiata["i"].substring(0, 2) == "DS") {
  console.log("FOUND")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function might be returning an empty object, you are then trying to access the 'i' property of that object which is gonna be undefined.

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer